# What is mattr_accessor in a Rails module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module, activesupport

I couldn't really find this in Rails documentation but it seems like **'mattr_accessor'** is the **Module** corollary for **'attr_accessor'** (getter & setter) in a normal Ruby **class**.

Eg. in a class

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name

  def set_fullname
    @name = "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end
end
```

Eg. in a module

```
module Authentication
  mattr_accessor :current_user

  def login
    @current_user = session[:user_id] || nil
  end
end
```

This helper method is provided by **ActiveSupport**.

Comment: [The docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-mattr_accessor) are better than the answers here.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Rails extends Ruby with both `mattr_accessor` (Module accessor) and `cattr_accessor` (as well as _`reader`/`_writer` versions).  As Ruby's `attr_accessor` generates getter/setter methods for *instances*, `cattr/mattr_accessor` provide getter/setter methods at the *class* or *module* level.  Thus:

```
module Config
  mattr_accessor :hostname
  mattr_accessor :admin_email
end
```

is short for:

```
module Config
  def self.hostname
    @hostname
  end
  def self.hostname=(hostname)
    @hostname = hostname
  end
  def self.admin_email
    @admin_email
  end
  def self.admin_email=(admin_email)
    @admin_email = admin_email
  end
end
```

Both versions allow you to access the module-level variables like so:

```
>> Config.hostname = "example.com"
>> Config.admin_email = "admin@example.com"
>> Config.hostname # => "example.com"
>> Config.admin_email # => "admin@example.com"
```

Comment: In your examples, you explain that `mattr_accessor` would be short for class instance variables (`@variable`s), but the source code seems to reveal they are actually setting/reading class variables. Could you please explain this difference?

Answer (score 40):

[Here's the source for `cattr_accessor`](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/2-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb)

And

[Here's the source for `mattr_accessor`](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/2-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors.rb)

As you can see, they're pretty much identical.

As to why there are two different versions? Sometimes you want to write `cattr_accessor` in a module, so you can use it for configuration info [like Avdi mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185573/what-is-mattraccessor-in-a-rails-module#185632).
However, `cattr_accessor` doesn't work in a module, so they more or less copied the code over to work for modules also.

Additionally,  sometimes you might want to write a class method in a module, such that whenever any class includes the module, it gets that class method as well as all the instance methods. `mattr_accessor` also lets you do this.

However, in the second scenario, it's behaviour is pretty strange. Observe the following code, particularly note the `@@mattr_in_module` bits

```
module MyModule
  mattr_accessor :mattr_in_module
end

class MyClass
  include MyModule
  def self.get_mattr; @@mattr_in_module; end # directly access the class variable
end

MyModule.mattr_in_module = 'foo' # set it on the module
=> "foo"

MyClass.get_mattr # get it out of the class
=> "foo"

class SecondClass
  include MyModule
  def self.get_mattr; @@mattr_in_module; end # again directly access the class variable in a different class
end

SecondClass.get_mattr # get it out of the OTHER class
=> "foo"
```

Comment: This was a gotcha that bit me pretty hard when setting default_url_options directly (a mattr_accessor).  Once class would set them one way and another would set them a different way, thus creating invalid links.

Comment: In latest version of Rails `cattr_*` are now aliases for `mattr_*`. See the [`cattr_accessor` source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb)