# How to call a module's attr_accessor variable from outside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I access `reserved_words` in the code below from outside?

```
module FriendlyId
   module Reserved
      module Configuration
         attr_accessor :reserved_words
      end
   end
end
```

Doing `FriendlyId::Reserved::Configuration.instance_variable_get(:reserved_words)` gives me the following error:

`NameError: 'reserved_words' is not allowed as an instance variable name`

Comment: Do you specifically need `attr_accessor` or could you use the extension that rails provides `mattr_accessor` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-mattr_accessor)

Comment: Try this ::FriendlyId::Reserved::Configuration.instance_variable_get(:reserved_words)

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185573/what-is-mattr-accessor-in-a-rails-module

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage of the `::attr_accessor`, and instance and class variable is the following. Since the `::attr_accessor` is just defines the pair of instance methods `#m`, and `m=`, the assignment to module can't be used for the module:

```
module M
   attr_accessor :m
end

M.instance_methods
# => [:m, :m=]
M.instance_variables
# => []
```

but it could be used for a class:

```
class A
   include M

   def initialize
      @m = 1
      @@mm = 2
   end

   def self.mm
      @@mm
   end
end

a = A.new
p a.m
# => 1
p A.mm
# => 2
p A.new.instance_variable_get( :@m )
# => 1
p A.class_variable_get( :@@mm )
# => 2
```

In above example, we defined class variable `@@mm`, and only in this case we can read it with `::class_variable_get` method, instance variable `@m` can be read only when the instance of class been created.